# rfc850 date format and NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Im having a hard tim getting the NSDateFormatter to give me a correct date format.  I need it to look like this:

```
Mon, 04 Jan 2010 10:10:00 GMT
```

But I am getting:

```
Mon, 04 Jan 2010 10:10:00 GMT+00:00
```

Using the format string:

```
EEE',' dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss z
```

No matter what value for timezone I use, the +00:00 appears to be stuck on the end.  I realize I could just remove it form the resulting string, but that feels like cheating.

So how do I get the date formatter to not include a time offset value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more research, I'm pretty sure this can't be done.  So my simple string manipulation will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when generating Http Date in RC1123 format.

http://blog.mro.name/2009/08/nsdateformatter-http-header/

Has some good information, but basically just replaces z with the fixed string 'GMT'.

Comment: lame or not - that's what the protocol defines.

Answer (score 0):

actually http://blog.mro.name/2009/08/nsdateformatter-http-header/ shows the correct way to do it, as the RFC allows the literal 'GMT' only and the NSDateFormatter is forced to timezone GMT and english weekday & month names.